# How to check that this event would occur after DOM is ready in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get page_tag information from the page and want to make sure that DOM for this page is already ready before getting the page tag information.

I am doing

```
$(document).ready(
{
   alert("test");
   var page_tag : $("head meta[name='page_tag']").attr('content');
   page_tag : (page_tag) ? page_tag : '';
}
```

But it gives me errors,

```
missing : after property id
alert("Check if document is ready");\n
```

Any suggestions on what could be the possible reasons for it or any other way of checking if the dom is ready or not before getting page_tag information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var page_tag = $("head meta[name='page_tag']").attr('content');
   alert(page_tag);
});
```

The ready() function requires you to pass in a function that it will execute when the document is ready.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error, you are using `:` instead of `=` to make the assignment:

```
var page_tag = $("head meta[name='page_tag']").attr('content');
page_tag = (page_tag) ? page_tag : '';
```

Or simply:

```
var page_tag = $("head meta[name='page_tag']").attr('content') || '';
```

The above will work, because the `attr` method returns a String or `undefined` if the attribute is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("test");
   var page_tag = $("head meta[name='page_tag']").attr('content');
   page_tag = (page_tag) ? page_tag : '';
}
```

You need to use a **=** instead of **:**